# Nail gun leaking air

Tags: tools, safety, air-leaks, air-compressor

What can I do if my nail gun leaks air through the chamber directly opposite from where it shoots nails? The gray part in the picture. Can it be dangerous?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not dangerous, but you'll eventually stop shooting nails. Chances are it's just a couple of o-rings that need replacing. Look for something like a 'cylinder rebuild kit'... should be well under 20 bucks.